# renewal token is not working in adal.js v1.0.14

Tags: angularjs, azure-active-directory, adal

I am using adal.js 1.0.14, below is my login

```
 var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);
    if (!config.popUp) {
        if (authenticationContext.isCallback(window.location.hash)) {
            authenticationContext.handleWindowCallback();
        }
    }
    var user = authenticationContext.getCachedUser();
    sessionStorage.setItem("adal:Tenant","@CommonMethods.GetAppConfigValue("ida:TenantId")")
    if (!user) {
        authenticationContext.login();
    }
```

below is my renewal code

```
this.authenticationContext.getCachedUser();
        this.authenticationContext.acquireToken(config.clientId, function (errorDesc, token) {
            if (errorDesc) {
                console.log("ErrorDesc", errorDesc);
            }
            if (token) {
                console.log("calling the Web API with the access token", token);
            }
        });
```

but i got "User login is required". Can't understand what happen with this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem, the problem is, I use below config settings for authentication

```
var config = {
tenant: window.sessionStorage.getItem('adal:Tenant'),
clientId: window.sessionStorage.getItem('adal.token.keys'),
redirectUri: baseURL,
popUp: false,
postLogoutRedirectUri: baseURL,
expireOffsetSeconds: 3540
```

}

in above code, the ClientId contain '|', because of which can't get token and user information. I update my config settings,

```
var config = {
tenant: window.sessionStorage.getItem('adal:Tenant'),
clientId: window.sessionStorage.getItem('adal.token.keys').replace('|', ''),
redirectUri: baseURL,
popUp: false,
postLogoutRedirectUri: baseURL,
expireOffsetSeconds: 3540
```

}

And it works.